# Python - Find matching elements between and within nested lists

Tags: python, list, nested

Background: I have a lengthy script which calculates possible chemical formula for a given mass (based on a number of criteria), and outputs (amongst other things) a code which corresponds to the 'class' of compounds which that formula belong to. I calculate formula from batches of masses which should all be members of the same class. However, given instrumentation etc limits, it is possible to calculate several possible formula for each mass. I need to check if any of the classes calculated are common to all peaks, and if so, return the position of the match/etc.

I'm struggling with working out how to do an iterative if/for loop which checks every combination for matches (**in an efficient way**).

The image included summarises the issue:
[image: http://imgur.com/0vfWW7J]

Or on actual screenshots of the data structure:
image link here - [image]

---

As you can see, I have a list called "formulae" which has a variable number of elements (in this case, 12). 
Each element in formulae is a list, again with a variable number of elements. 
Each element within those lists is a list, containing <strike>15</strike> 7 elements. <strike>I wish to compare the 11th element amongst different elements.</strike>

I.e.

```
formulae[0][0][11] == formulae[1][0][11]

formulae[0][0][11] == formulae[1][1][11]
...
formulae[0][1][11] == formulae[11][13][11]
```

I imagine the answer might involve a couple of nested `for` and `if` statements, but I can't get my head around it.
I then will need to export the lists which matched (like `formulae[0][0]`) to a new array.

Unless I'm doing this wrong?

Thanks for any help!

---

EDIT:
1- My data structure has changed slightly, and I need to check that elements [?][?][4] and [?][?][5] and [?][?][6] and [?][?][7] all match the corresponding elements in another list.

I've attempted to adapt some of the code suggested, but can't quite get it to work...

```
check_O = 4
check_N = 5
check_S = 6
check_Na = 7
# start with base (left-hand) formula
nbase_i = len(formulae)
for base_i in range(len(formulae)):    # length of first index
for base_j in range(len(formulae[base_i])):    # length of second index
    count = 0
    # check against comparison (right-hand) formula
    for comp_i in range(len(formulae)):    # length of first index
        for comp_j in range(len(formulae[comp_i])):    # length of second index
            if base_i != comp_i:
                o_test = formulae[base_i][base_j][check_O] == formulae[comp_i][comp_j][check_O]
                n_test = formulae[base_i][base_j][check_N] == formulae[comp_i][comp_j][check_N]
                s_test = formulae[base_i][base_j][check_S] == formulae[comp_i][comp_j][check_S]
                na_test = formulae[base_i][base_j][check_Na] == formulae[comp_i][comp_j][check_Na]
                if o_test == n_test == s_test == na_test == True:
                                    count = count +1
                else:
                    count = 0
            if count < nbase_i:
                        print base_i, base_j, comp_i,comp_j
                o_test = formulae[base_i][base_j][check_O] == formulae[comp_i][comp_j][check_O]
                n_test = formulae[base_i][base_j][check_N] == formulae[comp_i][comp_j][check_N]
                s_test = formulae[base_i][base_j][check_S] == formulae[comp_i][comp_j][check_S]
                na_test = formulae[base_i][base_j][check_Na] == formulae[comp_i][comp_j][check_Na]
                if o_test == n_test == s_test == na_test == True:
                            count = count +1
            else: 
                count = 0
            elif count == nbase_i:
                matching = "Got a match! " + "[" +str(base_i) + "][" + str(base_j) + "] matches with " + "[" + str(comp_i) + "][" + str(comp_j) +"]"
                print matching
        else:
            count = 0
```

Comment: supplying some usable input and what you want as output would be more useful than screenshots

Comment: what do you need the shape of your output to look like?

Comment: Thanks for the tip Padraic.

In the long run, I want to take all the [?][?] lists which match based on the criteria and export them to a new list/array, which we can think of as confidently assigned because they all have the same heteroatomic count.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at using `in` such as

```
agg = []
for x in arr:
    matched = [y for y in arr2 if x in y]
    agg.append(matched)
```

Answer (score 0):

Prune's answer not right, should be like this:

```
check_index = 11

# start with base (left-hand) formula
for base_i in len(formulae):    # length of first index
  for base_j in len(formulae[base_i]):    # length of second index

    # check against comparison (right-hand) formula
    for comp_i in len(formulae):    # length of first index
      for comp_j in len(formulae[comp_i]):    # length of second index
        if formulae[base_i][base_j][check_index] == formulae[comp_i][comp_j][check_index]:
          print "Got a match"
          # Here you add whatever info *you* need to identify the match
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've incorporated this, but tried to make it check elements conditionally... Im kinda stuck.

Comment: what do you mean by "make it check elements conditionally"

Comment: Imagine that the list "formulae" has three elements. For it to successfully match, it has to find a match between the first and second and first and third elements. 
I.e. formulae[0][1][11] == formulae[1][0][11] == formulae[2][3][11]. 
I imagine it should take all elements of formulae[0] and check them against all elements of formulae[1] till it finds a match. After that match, it needs to check formulae[2] for a match. If it cannot find a match, it should then loop back to the next element in formulae[0]... If it matches across all formulae[*], then it is a real match.

Comment: The difficulty being that the number of elements within formulae is variable, and the number of elements within each element of formulae is variable. 
The code as given can check if [0][0][7] matches and of the [1][*][7] series, but it doesnt then check [2][*][7]...

Comment: The code given will iterate ALL the items in the first two dimensions of formulae and compare it agains ALL the items in the first two dimensions again, checking the item 11 in the third dimension and reporting "Got a match".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your data structure, hence I'm not gonna write code here but propose an idea: how about an inverted index?

Like you scan once the lists creating kind of a summary of where the value you look for is.

You could create a dictionary composed as follows:

```
{ 
   'ValueOfInterest1': [ (position1), (position2) ],
   'ValueOfInterest2': [ (positionX) ]
}
```

Then at the end you can have a look at the dictionary and see if any of the values (basically lists) have length > 1.

Of course you'd need to find a way to create a position format that makes sense to you.

Just an idea.

Answer (score -2):

Does this get you going?

```
check_index = 11

# start with base (left-hand) formula
for base_i in len(formulae):    # length of first index
  for base_j in len(formulae[0]):    # length of second index

    # check against comparison (right-hand) formula
    for comp_i in len(formulae):    # length of first index
      for comp_j in len(formulae[0]):    # length of second index
        if formulae[base_i][base[j] == formulae[comp_i][comp_j]:
          print "Got a match"
          # Here you add whatever info *you* need to identify the match
```

Comment: Please add an explanation when you down-vote something; I need to learn what's more acceptable.